# How can i send a text or word file using the smtplib in Python?

Tags: python, smtp, smtpclient, smtplib

i searched on google but these examples are kind of tough for beginners like me..If there is any simple example of it...I know how send the html based messages

Answer (score 1):

```
import smtplib
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate





def send_mail(send_from,password send_to, subject, text, file=None,
              server="127.0.0.1"):

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text))


    with open(file, "rb") as fil:
        part = MIMEApplication(
            fil.read(),
            Name=basename(file)
        )
    # After the file is closed
    part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(file)
    msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(send_from, password )
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(send_from, send_to, text)
    server.quit()

send_mail('From','Password','ToMail','Subject','msg',r'FullPath')
```

Comment: what is that attachement in the 2nd last statement?

Comment: Just notice that I used  r' in the function call and this option relevant only for python 3.6 + , if  you use previous version just put it out and double all the slash instead

Comment: Refresh your page , I made it more explanatory

Comment: i understand most most of the part...but what to specify inplace of 'attachment'?

Comment: I ran your code but on my gmail inbox it is saying Address not found
Your message wasn't delivered to bilalgcu29@gmail because the domain gmail couldn't be found. Check for typos or unnecessary spaces and try again.

Comment: but still i can see the file being sent

Comment: To me its work perfect ,  have you entered your mail password to "Password" ??